# Why is variable name important in multiwidget template?

Tags: django, django-1.11

In my form i have a Multiwidget with 3 Textinputs.
I want to customize html output so in 1.11 i have to use new template api.
Clear so far.
My custom multiwidget template(99% copy/paste from docs) looks like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    {% for widget in widget.subwidgets %}
    <label class="col-md-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        {% include widget.template_name %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But i don't like using the same variable name 'widget' for multiwidget and subwidget.

So i replace

```
{% for widget in widget.subwidgets %}
{% include widget.template_name %}
```

with

```
{% for subwidget in widget.subwidgets %}
{% include subwidget.template_name %}
```

But it doesn't work. I get the same text input 3 times and this input has id, name and value from multiwidget, not from subwidgets(id without "_0", compressed value)

Is it a bug or my misunderstanding?

Comment: What are the contents of the template referred to by `widget.template_name`? If it uses `{{ widget }}`, then changing the variable name from `widget` to `subwidget` in the template is going to change the behaviour. It sounds like you might have to override that template and change `widget` to `subwidget` there.

Comment: i have already overwritten the template with my first code snippet, but it works only with "widget" as loop variable

Comment: What template is `{% include widget.template_name %}` including? You haven't shown that, unless it is including itself.

Comment: in both cases ('widget' as name and something else) template_name="django/forms/widgets/text.html" which is correct. but it populates with incorrect data

Comment: i understand now. 'widget' is "hardcoded" context for text.html. so i can use this name only if i want correct data in subwidgets or override subwidgets template. thx@Alasdair